# Conditional mapping in GAMS

Tags: mapping, gams-math

Consider the following data in GAMS:

```
set i        / 1,2,3 /
    j        / 1,2,3 /;

parameter stock(i,j);

stock(i,j) = 10;
```

Consider the following mapping:

```
set jagg            / b1,b2 /
    map2(j,jagg)    / 1.b1, 2.b1, 3.b2, 4.b2 /;
```

I can easily mapping using:

```
parameter stockagg(i,jagg);

stockagg(i,jagg) = sum(map2(j,jagg),stock(i,j));
```

However, I don't want to map if set *i* is equal to set *j*.
That is, I want the following data as my result:

```
1   1   10
1   b1  10
1   b2  20
2   b1  10
2   2   10
2   b2  20
3   b1  20
3   3   10
3   b2  10
4   b1  20
4   b2  10
4   4   10
```

Is there an easy way to do that in GAMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if I got your question completely right, but this give you the result you posted:

```
set i        / 1,2,3,4 /
    j        / 1,2,3,4,b1,b2 /;

Alias(j,jj);

parameter stock(i,j);

stock(i,j) = 10;

set jagg(j)       / b1,b2 /
    map2(j,jj)    / 1.b1, 2.b1, 3.b2, 4.b2 /;
    
parameter stockagg(i,j);

stockagg(i,j) =   sum(map2(jj,jagg(j))$(not sameas(i,jj)),stock(i,j))$(not sameas(i,j))
                + stock(i,j)                                         $(    sameas(i,j));

display stockagg;
```